# Windows UIAutomation sometimes hangs other apps

Tags: c#, com, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm using UIAutomation via COM interface in my WPF client app. Some users sometimes are taking hangs of their specific apps (like nVidia Control Panel). My app recieves that exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80131505): Operation
>   timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131505) 
>   in UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement.FindAll (TreeScope scope,
>   IUIAutomationCondition condition).

I cannot reproduce this on my PC.

- Do you have experience with that kind of problems?
- Do you have any workarounds for that cases?
- Can I somehow decrease COM timeout? maybe this will fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found some info about the issue.

- UIAutomation is unstable only on Windows 10 with Creator's Update ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c74b026-c84b-4256-9332-42e592a81e2d/update-1703-for-windows-10-enterprise-made-ui-automation-unstable?forum=win10itprogeneral))
- This is bug and it's submitted [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3135331/uiautomation-become-slow-after-windows-10-creators-update-1703)
- NickAb found a solution: Use `TreeWalker` ([source](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps.CodedUi/issues/6))

> Both `FindAll` and `FindFirst` are prone to this exception, which is
>   raised when trying to find elements in `WebView` that has loaded its
>   data recently, exception is thrown when methods try to build cache, so
>   it might be due to trying to iterate visual tree while it is being
>   rebuild by another thread.
>
> Replacing `FindAll` with
>
> ```
> private IEnumerable<WiniumElement> GetChildrens()
> {
>     var elementNode = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetFirstChild(this.AutomationElement);
>
>     while (elementNode != null)
>     {
>         yield return new WiniumElement(elementNode);
>         elementNode = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetNextSibling(elementNode);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Solves the problem. Needs further investigation. Most likely we will
>   have to replace both `FindFirst` and `FindAll` calls with custom
>   `TreeWalker` iteration method.
>
> This will solve the problem with not being able to get page source for
>   views with `WebView`s and not being able to find element in `WebView`
>   due to same error.